# Android LocationManager is filtering gps positions?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am developing gps positions correction algorithms.

I register onLocationChanged(Location location) listener to obtain current gps position when it changes.

```
MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // in Meters
MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds
...
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                    MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                    locationListener);
```

The problem is when I draw the points on map they seem to be already filtered.

Map -> http://postimg.org/image/l8ja9joht/

Measurements on the map are taken from samsung galaxy s+. When i took measurements from Nokia E52 (symbian) they had more random error. So I assume that andoird is filtering the measurements.

Can you please give me a hint on this? I can't find any info if the measurements are the raw gps positions from the receiver or post-filtered by android.

Comment: the dont look filtered, beside the stand still filter i mentioned below in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunatley ios and android both have a stand still filter enabled, which cannot disabled. This filter freezes your position when you are not moving. What you can try, is to disable GPS and restart every 2 seconds. Then you might get a new measured position.

Comment: but I am moving, the problem is that the new coordinates look like if they are filtered with kalman filter or some other algorithm when I receive them, anyway I'll try your idead to get new positions every next time interval with restarting the GPS

Comment: of course they are kalman filtered, every GPS chip I know (Sirf, ublox) does this. This is done in the GPS chips firmware, android could not disable that if the wanted.

Comment: ok now i get 1 measurement like so: locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(...) then i remove updates from the locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener) and then i register the listener for a new measurement, the errors are promissing from 30-90 meters near buildings, but i have to wait 10-15sec for new positions

Comment: this makes no sense, the technic i have proposed, is only suitable to disable the stand still filter. it makes no sense when you are moving.

Comment: well it somehow does, I get new measurements with random error so I'm quite sure they are not filtered, meaby you have another idea how to get raw gps data? I don't care about the battery life. I need the data only for testing algorithms

Comment: buy a ublox wintec202 receiver or any other. but then you still get normal data. pure raw date means the satellite singals itself, but this you probably cannot evaluate. if you can then you need a "raw license" which costs extra! look on ublox homepage if you are  really want to handle raw GPS (RINEX)

Comment: I'm getting enforma Mini MT soon :)